# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/guava30/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using flink 1.17.1 and java version 11 .

I am getting below error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList

Need solution for above issue ,please let me know

Comment: Hi. You should be more specific if you want a solution. Because the information you gave is very generic. There could be thousand's reasons for your error and there is no straight away solution.  Try to give some context, what you trying to do, an example of your code, your environment, in which moment you have your error....

Answer (score 1):

For `ClassNotFoundException` errors, this is almost assuredly an issue where your given Flink application didn't compile one or more of the expected dependencies when you packaged it (e.g. compiled into a jar/shaded jar) prior to deploying the job. Since they aren't packaged in the application, you'll encounter these errors at runtime when the classes are referenced by your code.

If you are using Maven, you'll want to ensure that you have the appropriate package (in this case the Flink Shaded Guava package) as a compiled dependency in your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
    <version>${flink-shaded-guava-version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Obviously, if you are using something like Gradle, the syntax will vary. It's probably worth reviewing over all of your projects dependencies and ensuring compatibility across packages and versions (e.g. your version of Apache Flink, etc.)